# Move and stretch Line2D shape with mouse

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, java-2d, mouselistener

I want to move and stretch a `Line2D` shape with mouse. I tried but was facing some issues. While moving it suddenly moves in various directions. I was facing issues with:

```
shape.setLine(p1,p2);
```

EDIT:

Earlier I had faced some problems.

But I could make it work now hence thought to post here.

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lines");

```
    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        private Shape line = null;
        {
            line = new Line2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 200);
            prevPoint = new Point();
            newPoint = new Point();

            MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                    System.out.println("Prev Point=" + prevPoint.toString());
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    int dx = 0;
                    int dy = 0;

                    dx = (int) (prevPoint.x - e.getPoint().getX());
                    dy = (int) (prevPoint.y - e.getPoint().getY());

                    Line2D shape = (Line2D) line;

                    int x1 = (int) (shape.getX1() - dx);
                    int y1 = (int) (shape.getY1() - dy);

                    int x2 = (int) (shape.getX2() - dx);
                    int y2 = (int) (shape.getY2() - dy);

                    Point startPoint = new Point(x1, y1);
                    Point endPoint = new Point(x2, y2);

                    if (shape != null) {
                        shape.setLine(startPoint, endPoint);
                        prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }

            };
            addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
            addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            if (line != null) {
                g2d.draw(line);
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setSize(650, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to include more information. Try to provide a minimal code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: plus 1 to expanding on your question